# Differences Audit logs and Most popular items

Tags: analytics, audit-log-reports

On our site there's a discrepancy between the data in the audit logs and that in the Most popular items. I ran an audit log for the last 14 days and find in most cases the audit log has significantly higher numbers (for instance 100 views in MPI vs 700+ views in the audit log)

Which one is the most reliable source and where is the difference coming from?

Answer (score 4):

The audit logs is more accurate.

The "Most popular items" has a default threshold of 3 views within 24 hours for the count to increase.

Ex.

- 2 people views a document in one day

  - Audit log will increase by 2
  - Most popular items will not increase at all
- 3 people views a document in one day

  - Audit log will increase by 3
  - Most popular items will also increase by 3
- 4 people views a document in one day

  - Audit log will increase by 4
  - Most popular items will also increase by 4

More about `TailTrimming`, how it works and how to configure it [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2014/01/23/view-and-configure-usage-analytics-reports-in-sharepoint-server-2013/#TailTrimming)

Comment: Wow - I wasn't aware of trimming! Things make a lot more sense now. I'm sure Microsoft has its reasons for implementing like this, but I don't see how it makes sense. How is most popular items even useful with a setting like this?

Comment: That's a good question. My guess it it comes down to performance in the end

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint Online, Audit Logs will not include events like File Accessed, File Downloaded, FileSyncDownloaded and PageViewed.

So there will be discrepancy in Audit Logs and Site Usage reports. If you want correct data use SharePoint Activity reports.